# Catkin/Ros "undefined reference to"

Tags: c++, ros, catkin

I'm trying to build a project with ROS, but I keep getting "undefined reference to <>" errors, for exemple :

```
    CMakeFiles/robot_controller_node.dir/src/Node_Robot_Controller.cpp.o: dans la fonction « main »:
    Node_Robot_Controller.cpp:(.text+0x1f1): référence indéfinie vers « trajectoryclass::trajectoryclass(ros::NodeHandle) »
    Node_Robot_Controller.cpp:(.text+0x796): référence indéfinie vers « List_Container::getElement(int) »
    Node_Robot_Controller.cpp:(.text+0x7ab): référence indéfinie vers « Task_Interface::getTaskDescription() »
    Node_Robot_Controller.cpp:(.text+0x7d1): référence indéfinie vers « List_Container::getElement(int) »
    Node_Robot_Controller.cpp:(.text+0x7d9): référence indéfinie vers « Task_Interface::getTaskId() »
    Node_Robot_Controller.cpp:(.text+0x83a): référence indéfinie vers « List_Container::getElement(int) »
    Node_Robot_Controller.cpp:(.text+0x977): référence indéfinie vers « List_Container::next() »
    Node_Robot_Controller.cpp:(.text+0xa60): référence indéfinie vers « List_Container::getElement(int) »
    Node_Robot_Controller.cpp:(.text+0xa68): référence indéfinie vers « Task_Interface::getTaskId() »
    Node_Robot_Controller.cpp:(.text+0xab5): référence indéfinie vers « List_Container::getElement(int) »
    Node_Robot_Controller.cpp:(.text+0xadd): référence indéfinie vers « List_Container::isEmpty() »
    /home/tcozic/Documents/git_ur10/catkin_ws/devel/lib/librobot_controller_library.so: référence indéfinie vers « error_norm(std::vector >, std::vector >) »
    /home/tcozic/Documents/git_ur10/catkin_ws/devel/lib/librobot_controller_library.so: référence indéfinie vers « Position_Joint::getVector() »
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[2]: *** [/home/tcozic/Documents/git_ur10/catkin_ws/devel/lib/ur10/robot_controller_node] Erreur 1
    make[1]: *** [ur10/CMakeFiles/robot_controller_node.dir/all] Erreur 2
    make: *** [all] Erreur 2
    Invoking "make install -j4 -l4" failed
```

This is my CmakeLists.txt for the compilation of this package :

```
<pre><code>
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(ur10)

set(MSG_DEPS
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  trajectory_msgs
  moveit_msgs
)


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  message_generation
  moveit_core
  moveit_ros_planning
  moveit_ros_planning_interface
  dynamic_reconfigure
  moveit_ros_move_group
  pcl_conversions ##adding
  pcl_msgs ##adding
  roscpp
  rospy
  roslib
  #tf
  #urdf
  genmsg
 ${MSG_DEPS}
)




find_package(VISP REQUIRED)
find_library(VISP_LIBRARIES NAMES visp HINTS ${VISP_LIBRARY_DIRS} )

find_package(PCL REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

find_package( ur_package REQUIRED)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
 add_message_files(
   FILES
   Task_move.msg
   Task_wait.msg
   Piece.msg
   Task.msg
   Task_tool.msg
 )
# Generate services in the 'srv' folder
 add_service_files(
   FILES
   Validation.srv
   NewPiece.srv
 )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs  # Or other packages containing msgs
 )
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime roscpp rospy roslib moveit_core moveit_ros_planning_interface   #moveit_plan_execution
 moveit_trajectory_execution_manager moveit_ros_planning  moveit_planning_scene_monitor ${MSG_DEPS}
  DEPENDS VISP OpenCV
)


###########
## Build ##
###########


include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++11" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++0x" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
elseif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x")
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "The compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no C++11 support. Please use a different C++ compiler. Suggested solution: update the pkg build-essential ")
endif()


## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${ur_package_INCLUDE_DIRS})

## Declare a C++ library
 add_library(robot_controller_library
     src/List_Container/List_Container.cpp

     src/Piece_Description/Piece.cpp

     src/Robot_Description/Robot.cpp
     src/Robot_Description/Tool.cpp
     src/Robot_Description/Tool_IO_Config.cpp

     src/Position/Position_Interface.cpp
     src/Position/Position_Joint.cpp
     src/Position/Position_TCP.cpp

     src/Task/Task_Move.cpp
     src/Task/Task_Tool.cpp
     src/Task/Task_Wait.cpp
 )
add_dependencies(robot_controller_library ur10_gencpp)

# Declare a C++ executable
add_executable(robot_controller_node src/Node_Robot_Controller.cpp)
 #add_dependencies(robot_controller ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
 target_link_libraries(robot_controller_node  robot_controller_library ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${VISP_LIBRARIES})


</code></pre>
```

All *.cpp files are classes, with theirs own headers in the include/ur10/ [Directory_name]/directories, except for the Node_controller_node.cpp

This is my first big project with ROS and I don't understand where the problem come from....

Thanks in advance for your help !

Edit : I tried to compile the library without the node:

```
 


## Declare a C++ library
set(SOURCE_robot_controller_library
     src/List_Container/List_Container.cpp

     src/Piece_Description/Piece.cpp

     src/Robot_Description/Robot.cpp
     src/Robot_Description/Tool.cpp
     src/Robot_Description/Tool_IO_Config.cpp

     src/Position/Position_Interface.cpp
     src/Position/Position_Joint.cpp
     src/Position/Position_TCP.cpp

     src/Task/Task_Move.cpp
     src/Task/Task_Tool.cpp
     src/Task/Task_Wait.cpp


     src/Task/Task_Interface.cpp

 )
add_library(Robot_controller_lib ${SOURCE_robot_controller_library})
add_dependencies(Robot_controller_lib ur10_gencpp)
target_link_libraries(Robot_controller_lib
        ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
        ${VISP_LIBRARIES})
```

I don't have any errrors, but I keep getting the reference error when I try to add the compilation of the node :

```
add_executable(robot_controller_node src/Node_Robot_Controller.cpp)
add_dependencies(robot_controller_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(robot_controller_node 
    Robot_controller_lib
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
        ${VISP_LIBRARIES})
```

PS: I can't post code here, it is for a professionnal project.

Could it be a probleme with the use of inheritance or virtual functions with catkin ? The classes List_Container and Task_Interface possess virtual functions and inherit others class. I already make sure that all functions have been implemented.

Comment: It looks like things here are getting pretty complicated to tell the exact solution, but I would suggest that you try to compile only `robot_controller_library` as it looks like it's the one throwing errors and no other dependencies are needed for it's building. So, restart simple, get the library files to compile then add the other libraries... Keep it simple, keep it clear !

Comment: *Possibly* (I'm not sure about this), you are clearing out some necessary flags: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")`. You could give this: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} "-std=c++11")` a try instead.

Comment: I just edited the post for the building without the node.

if I replace by:

    <code>
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} 
    </code>

 I get the following error :
    <code>
    c++: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.
    /bin/sh: 1: -std=c++11: not found
    make[2]: *** [ur10/CMakeFiles/Robot_controller_lib.dir/src/List_Container/List_Container.cpp.o] Erreur 127
    </code>